# No severity count for one user in one project

Tags: sonarqube

Recently for one user in a project all of the severity issues are showing at 0, while for a different user with the exact same permissions it shows correctly

The user has tried clearing cache, and the issue even persisted when switching computers.

[image: How it should be] [image: How it is for one user]

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this before? Does SonarQube have any kind of user specific cache? Would restarting fix this?

Comment: Does the user has the same problem on other projects?

Comment: Well SonarQube just fixed itself, right when I asked this. : /